# Apache configuration. How to forbid root folders viewing

Tags: apache

I've added VirtualHost 

    ServerAdmin root@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/blogovet.ru
    ServerName www.blogovet.ru
    ServerAlias blogovet.ru

But my script in this domain can see all server files  /* not only in his directory /var/www/html/blogovet.ru

How to forbid viewing files except DocumentRoot ?

Answer (score 0):

A script will be able to read all files that the user running the script can read.  So you should make sure your web server does not run as root (it needs to be started as root to listen on port 80, but should swich user to e.g. "www" itself), and then make sure that that user can't read any sensible files.

You could also use SElinux for an extra layer of security.

Comment: You need to start apache as root, but you should configure it to swich to another user after listening to port 80.  See the User and Group apache configuration directives.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution for PHP (If disable cgi and ssi, looks good)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin root@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site.com
    ServerName www.site.com
    ServerAlias site.com
    ErrorLog /var/www/html/site.com/error-log
#    TransferLog /var/www/html/site.com/transfer-log
#    CustomLog /var/www/html/site.com/access-log common
    <IfModule mod_php5.c>
        php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir "/tmp"
        php_admin_value include_path ".:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php:/var/www/html/site.com"
        php_admin_value open_basedir "/var/www/html/site.com"
        php_admin_value doc_root "/var/www/html/site.com"
    </IfModule>
    <Directory "/var/www/html/site.com">
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Here, a php script _can_ still access any readable files in the file system, but the specific script php_admin will attempt to only access certain files.

Comment: False sense of security. As Rasmus pointed out, you can just shell_exec() and still be able to do everything. Unless you plan on dropping all of those functions as well.